# How to send iterators to laravel queue job

Tags: php, laravel-5

When trying to send array payload of 100K records to a Laravel job (Horizon and Redis), it's throwing memory issue:

```
Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77598720 bytes)
```

Memory is set to 512MB.

The code I've used is

```
CreateSmsBroadcast::dispatch($user, $smsBroadcast, iterator_to_array($contacts),
 $requestData)->onQueue('create-sms-broadcast');
```

When passing payload `contacts (iterator)`,

```
CreateSmsBroadcast::dispatch($user, $smsBroadcast, $contacts, $requestData)
->onQueue('create-sms-broadcast');
```

then getting following issue:

```
    // vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php
    protected function createObjectPayload($job)
    {
        return [
            'displayName' => $this->getDisplayName($job),
            'job' => 'Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call',
            'maxTries' => $job->tries ?? null,
            'timeout' => $job->timeout ?? null,
            'timeoutAt' => $this->getJobExpiration($job),
            'data' => [
                'commandName' => get_class($job),
                'command' => serialize(clone $job), // line of error
            ],
        ];
    }

Serialization of 'Generator' is not allowed
```

I do not want to increase the memory. So please suggest me on how shall I fix above issue?

Comment: use this
        `ini_set('memory_limit', -1);` it is unlimit memory

Comment: @Davit, I do not want to increase memory